# Angular2/JavaScript - How can I show all the localStorage saved variables and get the total length of all keys?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on an Angular2 app, in which I need to store items that were added by the user to the shopping cart. For that, I am using local storage to save the items temporarily. Each category (ex. shoes, clothes....) is saved in the local storage as a key; its value is an array that contains all the added items and belongs to the same category `key`.

I have multiple keys, each of them has a value which is an array.
I want to access to the stored keys and also get the length of value of all keys

Ex:
key 1 has a value that has a length of 5.
Key 2 has a value that has a length of 12.

So the total length is 12+5=17

Any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(localStorage).length` is really simple if you don't mind the extra quotes (which you can replace() if needed), otherwise, use `Object.keys(localStorage)` and loop

Comment: JSON.stringify(localStorage).length works only when you have one object

Comment: a few confusing things: localStorage only stores strings, not array or objects, so it's unclear if by stored array length you want char or element counts. do you have a naming convention where different localStorage keys have a number on the end of the category to define keys? if that's the case, loop through them and add up the sizes: `var shoeSpace = Object.keys(localStorage).filter(/./.test, /^shoes\d+$/).map(a=>localStorage[a].length).reduce((a,b)=>a+b)`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just store it all on an object and JSON.stringify it to save, JSON.parse to load (Angular2 may have a better method of accessing localstorage).

```
var store = {
   "categories" : {
       "shoes" : ['key1', 'key2'],
       "clothes" : []
    }

}

function getCategoryLength(cat){
    var total = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < store.categories[cat].length){
       total += store.categories[cat][i].length;
    }
    return total
}
getCategoryLength("shoes")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access keys with `Object.keys` like below

```
var storedKeys = Object.keys(localStorage);
//length = storedKeys.length 



/*
//Assuming your have store structure like below
  localStorage = {
                    key1: [1, 2, 3],
                    key2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                    key3: "text"
                 };
*/

var flattenKeysLength = 0;
for(var key in localStorage) 
    flattenKeysLength += 
        (typeof localStorage[key] == "string")? 1:localStorage[key].length;
```